# Alternatives to dog bone

Tags: dogs

We have a dog who around two months ago gave birth to a pup. My vet suggests me to get a dog bone for the pup because he likes to chew things. However the dog bone happens to be non-vegetarian and if I ever bring it (the dog bone) home chances are I will get thrown out of the house.

Are there some vegan alternatives to dog bones which I can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been happy with [Kong chew toy products](https://www.kongcompany.com/products/for-dogs/) - very durable.

Also, a length of sturdy rope with a knot tied at the end. Not just any old rope from a hardware store - you'll want to find something which isn't chemically treated. Try something like [hemp fiber rope](https://www.earthdog.com/hemp-rope-dog-toys.html). If your dog doesn't care for it, soak it in some flavor (like used cooking oil or vegetable soup base). Or, just play tug with them with it and they'll get into it.

Your dog needs meat tho, so a vegan household will need to make peace with that to make a healthy home for the four legged members of your family. Note that a vegan diet is terrible for a dog. If it becomes an option, soup bones from the local butcher not only can be boiled for GREAT soup stock (for you or the dog) but after cooking they can, [with caution](http://www.petmd.com/dog/nutrition/evr_dg_raw_bones_or_cooked_bones?page=2), be appropriate chew toys. I have found this to be a very economically thrifty means of utilizing an animal product which likely would otherwise just get thrown away. If it helps, you could think of using the soup bone as a way of honoring the cow's life.

That said, [this article has a list of good vegan suggestions](http://urbanvegan.net/natural-dog-chews/) - I particularly like the sweet potato dog chew rope, but you'll want to balance the food consumption of the chew toy with their overall food intake.

Answer (score 1):

Chewing bones is terrible for a dog's teeth, and there is a risk fragments could break off which could cause potentially life-threatening gastrointestinal obstruction.

There are plenty of safe alternatives for chew toys available at any pet store. I caution you against making your own chew toys, because they are more likely to break/disintegrate, which could result in your dog ingesting part of it.

Comment: "[While chewing the correct sized bone is generally safe, regularly inspect your pet’s teeth and gums for any abrasions or cracked teeth, and have your veterinarian check the mouth at least twice annually for signs of periodontal disease.](http://www.petmd.com/dog/nutrition/evr_multi_raw_bones_dental_health_for_pets)"

Comment: They are as many problems with manufactured chew toys - even those intended for ingestion: http://healthypets.mercola.com/sites/healthypets/archive/2009/09/01/why-all-your-healthy-pet-efforts-may-be-worthless-if-you-do-this.aspx